# nodejs - escaping variable character within .env

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

My .env has, say, two simple variables:

USERNAME:"myusername"
PASSWORD:"mypassword&7"

The thing is, when I try to use shell.exec to pass a git clone command, it seems to be ignoring the '&7'from my password variable.

```
shell.exec(`git clone https://${process.env.USERNAME}:${process.env.USERNAME}@github.com/my-repo/xyz-git-ops.git`);
```

it outputs:

> /bin/sh: 7@gmy-repo/xyz-git-ops.git: No such file or directory
> Cloning into 'mypassword'...
> fatal: unable to access 'https://myusername:mypassword/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

I notice a few weird stuff:

1 - it ignores the last 2 characters of my password value, the '&7'and the git clone output replaces it with a '/'instead.

2 - if I do `console.log(process.env.USERNAME)`, it prints the value perfectly: mypassword&7

All that makes me wonder if is there a way of either escaping the '&' char from the password value or if my approach to pass credential via `shell.exec()` is absolutely mistaken. Bellow is the full content of my .js file

```
const nodeCron = require("node-cron");
const shell = require('shelljs');
const rpath = '/Users/myuser/Documents/Git Ops Cron/repos';
require('dotenv').config();
const start = Date.now();
const username = process.env.USERNAME
const password = process.env.PASSWORD

async function xyzGitOps(){
    console.log("Running scheduled job", start);
    shell.cd(rpath);
    shell.exec(`git clone https://${username}:${password}@github.com/my-repo/xyz-git-ops.git`);
    return console.log("Job finished");
}

const job = nodeCron.schedule("* * * * *", xyzGitOps);
```

Answer (score 2):

The username/password component of a URL should be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

The `node:url` [URL](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/url.html#class-url) class will do this for you

```
const repo = new URL(`https://github.com/my-repo/xyz-git-ops.git`)
repo.username = process.env.USERNAME
repo.password = process.env.PASSWORD
```

The URL's `.toString()` encodes the values:

```
> String(repo)
'https://userw:pass%%2F%40%23$@github.com/my-repo/xyz-git-ops.git'
> `${repo}`
'https://userw:pass%%2F%40%23$@github.com/my-repo/xyz-git-ops.git'
```

Comment: Interesting. If I do repo.href, then I can see the string the way it was supposed to be. But it doesn't help doing shell.exec passing the `repo.username` and `repo.password` among the url (e. g. `shell.exec(`git clone https://${repo.username}:${repo.password}@github.com/my-repo/xyz-git-ops.git`);`) I get the same error message. It tries to clone into a folder whose name was taken from my actual password value. As explained above. @Matt

Comment: The string representation of the whole URL, I've updated the example